# Injecting html into asp.net string for e-mail

Tags: c#, asp.net, html, string

Currently I'm sending an HTML e-mail I'm creating out of asp.net strings is outputting links as plain text rather than hyperlinks, which is what I'm going for.  The code for generating the e-mail string looks like this:

```
 Uri link = new Uri("http://www.somesite.com");

string body = "Plus, you may wish to bookmark " + link + " for your rate comparison needs."

string subject = Resources.Email.VerificationEmailSubject;

Email.SendEmail(email, subject, body);

   public static void SendEmail(string toAddress, string subject, string body)
    {
        try
        {

            MailMessage mailMessage = new MailMessage();
            mailMessage.To.Add(new MailAddress(toAddress));
            mailMessage.Subject = subject;
            mailMessage.IsBodyHtml = true;
            mailMessage.Body = body;

            using (SmtpClient smtpClient = new SmtpClient())
            {
                smtpClient.Send(mailMessage);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            LogManager log = new LogManager();
            log.LogError(typeof(Email), ex);
        }
    }
```

What is the simplest way to do this?

Thanks!

Edit 1:

Tried -

```
string emailContent = "Plus, you may wish to bookmark <a href='" + link + "'>www.comparsave.com</a> for your rate comparison needs.";
```

Viewing the email source, the string is being html encoded by asp.net to render as plain text in html: < and > are being replaced by "& gt;" "& lt;" etc. How to stop asp.net from doing this??

Edit 2:

Okay, figured it out! Will post the answer later when I have time. Thanks all!

Comment: can you also post the code calling that method?

Answer (score 3):

If it's an HTML email, do this:

```
"<a href='" + link + "'>" + link + "</a>"
```

Comment: This gives me: 

Plus, you may wish to bookmark <a href='http://www.comparasave.com/'>www.comparsave.com</a> for your rate comparison needs.

Comment: That `<a>` tag should disappear when the email arrives in your inbox, and you should just see link, as long as you are sending it as HTML.

Comment: I'm viewing it as a .mht file in internet explorer. Any idea if this would  be giving it problems?

Comment: I don't know what .mht is, but yes, probably. Can you try looking at it in your email (Outlook, Gmail, etc.)?

Comment: Viewed it in outlook...same problem :(

Comment: Do you have any other formatting (fonts, colors, etc.) at all in your email? I bet you're sending the email as plain text instead of a HTML. On your `MailMessage`, try putting `message.IsBodyHtml = true`.

Comment: It's being sent as an HTML e-mail :S

Comment: Can you post the rest of your code between forming the string and sending the email?

Comment: Did you find a solution to this? It must be getting sent as plain text somehow. Did you try it in any other mail clients?

Answer (score 1):

Use a template and insert your links into it. E.g.

```
const string template = "Plus, you may wish to bookmark <a href='{0}'>{0}</a> for your rate comparison needs."

string htmlEmailBody = String.Format(template, link);
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to use Html.Raw from within a cshtml file acting as the email template. For some reason I wasn't able to call Html.Raw in the cs file posted above.